# Derivative of a 2D Interpolating function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation

I cannot find a way to obtain the partial derivatives of a 2D Interpolating Function obtained with `ListInterpolation`. I didn't find anything useful on the web. Any clue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another form I have found useful is:

```
f = ListInterpolation[
  Table[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1, .25}, {y, 0, 2, .25}], {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}]
```

Then one can make derivative functions that can be treated as normal function via

```
dfdx[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[f[x, y], {x, 1}]]
dfdy[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[f[x, y], {y, 1}]]
```

and the second derivatives

```
d2fdx[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[f[x, y], {x, 2}]]
d2fdy[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[f[x, y], {y, 2}]]
```

the partial with respect to x and then y

```
dfdydx[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[f[x, y], x, y]]
```

or as pointed out by J.M. a more compact and very readable form:

```
dfdx = Derivative[1, 0][f]
dfdy = Derivative[0, 1][f]
dfdydx = Derivative[1, 1][f]
```

Comment: More compact: `dfdx = Derivative[1, 0][f]; dfdy = Derivative[0, 1][f]; dfdydx = Derivative[1, 1][f];`, and so forth.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, this form is very readable and compact. I added it.

Answer (score 3):

Using an example from the documentation of `ListInterpolation`:

```
f = ListInterpolation[
  Table[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1, .25}, {y, 0, 2, .25}], {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}]
dfdx[u_, v_] := D[f[x, y], x] /. {x -> u, y -> v}
dfdy[u_, v_] := D[f[x, y], y] /. {x -> u, y -> v}
Manipulate[
 Show[{Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}], 
   Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.03], 
     Table[Point[{x, y, Sin[x y]}], {x, 0, 1, .25}, {y, 0, 2, .25}], 
     Blue, Thick, 
     Arrow[{{p, q, f[p, q]}, {p, q, f[p, q]} - 
        Normalize[{dfdx[p, q], dfdy[p, q], -1}]}]}]}, 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {0, 2}}], {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please make your question clear.

But I think you're simply using `f'[x,y]` and hope that you can get a result?

Try the following code:

```
f = ListInterpolation[
  Table[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1, .25}, {y, 0, 2, .25}], {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}]

D[f[x, y], x]

Plot3D[Evaluate@D[f[x, y], x], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

for higher order:

```
D[f[x,y],{x,2}]
```

Will this code help?

Also, you may want a derivatives on a certain direction:

```
Ddir[f_, {x0_, y0_}] := Normalize[{x0, y0}].{f[x, y]~D~x, f[x, y]~D~y}

Plot3D[Evaluate@Ddir[f, {1, 1}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

I hate these simple copy work of documentation. Please check the documentation up next time you ask.